# Twilio Client Cannot set property 'audio' of undefined in Ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic3, twilio

I did use twilio-client in my ionic app and every time I pass the responsibility token it returns `TypeError: Cannot set property 'audio' of undefined {stack: (...), message: "Cannot set property 'audio' of undefined"}`

Instantiating the device like this:

`const Device = require('twilio-client').Device;`

and passing the responsibility token:

`const device = Device(resp.token);`

This part here will return `TypeError: Cannot set property 'audio' of undefined {stack: (...), message: "Cannot set property 'audio' of undefined"}`

I did try passing 2nd parameter, but it's still not working.

`const device = Device(resp.token, {
   rtcConfiguration: { iceTransportPolicy: 'relay' }
 });`

Comment: Hmm... this might be because Twilio Client JS uses APIs that aren't supported in the in app browser. Perhaps try this cordova plugin: https://github.com/jefflinwood/twilio_client_phonegap